# devtools install_github fails

Tags: r, devtools

I've tried everything I could think of but still can't get this to work. I think it has to do with indentation as it works fine locally(build version). Here is the error I get:

> Error in read.dcf(path) : 
>     Found continuation line starting '    dplyr(>= 0.7.8), ...' at begin of record.

Sample of my code:

```
Imports: 
    dplyr(>= 0.7.8),
    caret(>= 6.0-81),
    tidyr(>= 0.8.2),
    reshape2(>= 1.4.3),
    plyr(>= 1.8.4),
    magrittr(>= 1.5)
```

How I tried to install:

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr")
```

I did get the same earlier and solved it by limiting my description to a single line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try adding a space `dplyr (>= 0.7.8)`?

Comment: Same. I've found it to be a common issue that is still open here: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1900 and I apparently commented to have solved it 2 days ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed like this which also worked for me according to: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1978

- Run `devtools::install_github("r-lib/remotes")`
- Restart R.
- Run `devtools::install_github("...")` for the intended package.

Comment: What package were you trying to install? What is your devtool/remotes version?

Comment: Solved using this workaround, [https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/130#issuecomment-423830669](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/130#issuecomment-423830669)